# Testing this command

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, mvvm, catel

I'm quite new to unit tests and I've got some troubles testing this command

```
internal async Task OnDeleteTreasurerCommandExecute(TesorieraItemResult tesoriera)
    {
        try
        {
            if (await MessageService.ShowAsync("Confermare l'operazione?", string.Empty, MessageButton.YesNo, MessageImage.Question) == MessageResult.Yes)
            {
                await repository.DeleteTesorieraItemAsync(tesoriera.ID_ISTITUTO,tesoriera.ID_DIVISA,tesoriera.PROGRESSIVO);

                await MessageService.ShowInformationAsync("Operazione completata");

                if (SelectedInstitute != null)
                    await OnLoadDataCommandExecute();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorService.HandleError(GetType(), ex);
        }
    }
```

I'm using Catel as MVVM framework

how do I simulate the yes/no answers?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to substitute the MessageService with a class that can return yes or no answer. Here's an example using [`NSubstitute`](http://nsubstitute.github.io/).

1. `Install-Package NSubstitute`
2. `Install-Package NUnit`
3. Let us say you have a class that has a method that 
   needs Yes, then No:

   ```
   public class AccountViewModel
   {
       readonly IMessageService _messageService;
       readonly ICustomerRepository _customerRepository;

       public AccountViewModel(IMessageService messageService, ICustomerRepository customerRepository)
       {
           _messageService = messageService;
           _customerRepository = customerRepository;
       }

       public async Task OnDeleteCustomer(Customer customer)
       {
           if (await MessageService.ShowAsync(
              "Confirm?", 
               string.Empty, 
               MessageButton.YesNo, 
               MessageImage.Question) == MessageResult.Yes)
           {
               _customerRepository.Delete(customer);
               await MessageService.ShowInformationAsync("Completed");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Then your test case looks like this:

```
public class TestAccountViewModel
{
    [TestCase]
    public class TestDeleteCustomer()
    {
        // arrange
        var messageService = Substitute.For<IMessageService>();
        messageService
            .ShowAsync(
                Arg.Any<string>(),
                Arg.Any<string>(),
                Arg.Any<MessageButton>(),
                Arg.Any<MessageImage>())
            .Returns(Task.FromResult(MessageResult.Yes);

        messageService
            .ShowInformationAsync(Arg.Any<string>())
            .Returns(Task.FromResult<object>(null));

        var customerRepository = Substitute.For<ICustomerRepository>();

        // act
        var sut = new AccountViewModel(messageService, customerRepository);
        var customer = new Customer();
        sut.OnDeleteCustomer(customer);

        // assert
        Assert.IsTrue(customerRepository.Received().DeleteCustomer(customer));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a past version, Catel provided a test implementation of the IMessageService that allowed you to queue expected results so you could test the different paths inside a command.

I just noticed this class is no longer available, but you can easily implement a test stub yourself (using mocking, etc). Or you could contribute to Catel and revive the test implementation.

Comment: Hello Geert, as I've wrote you I'm quite new to unit testing and everything related (mocking, etc..)  in which version that feature was present? Thanks

Comment: A few versions back, can't recall.